# Dynamic Web based template designer to generate pdfs (from database data)

Tags: php, .net, database, templates, pdf-generation

I am currently working on a project for which I haven't found a solution yet, although i've been searching the web (stackoverflow included, obviously) for nearly 2 days.

The company i am working for has the need of gerating several kinds of pdfs: machine/product labels (small ones with info), product trial/test reports (typically A4 size, several values), and any other kind that shows up. All the company's data is the cloud in SQL-Server and the application needs to be web based as well, so that it can be used by anyone around the world (Suppliers, clients, colaborators).

Basically, some years ago a php script was done using TCPDF so the IT guys could create report templates programatically, that could be used anywhere. Nowadays, they use the same script but they create the templates in a web application done in VB.NET but it is not the perfect solution because it is full of bugs and limitations.

What is expected is an **application that anyone** (from the receptionist to the administrator) **can use**, **that allows the generation of a custom template** that will **later be used to generate pdfs** with the desired **data fetched** from their **database**.

As far as I see, there are 3 options:

1 - Use some kind of commercial or free tool which is already done and being used by other companies. Although it seems odd, i couldn't find a tool for this. How come there isn't one, considering that basically any big company needs to generate several types of pdfs everyday?

2 - Correct the existing VB.net application and php script, extending its functionality and reliability;

3 - Come up with a completely new approach for this. I've been thinking in creating a web app that allows people to drag and drop elements so that they can build the desired template (vb.net?c#?). Export this template to xml/json. Use this template and the set of fetched vars from the database to generate the pdf using any of the available tools (FPDF, TCPDF, or any other kind of php tool [php is desired to maintain the usability of the current working templates]).

I would really appreciate any kind of input, brainstorm or wild ideas.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is not a good fit for our Q/A format, as it's likely to solicit open discussion and debate. For the types of questions that are good for StackOverflow, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/which-types-of-programming-related-questions-are-appropriate. You have a very excellently detailed description of the problem, but it is too broad in scope. If you need help with a **specific programming issue**, be sure to provide us with what you have tried.

Comment: Dear Aaron, I do understand your point there.I've seen many questions related to this one, but any exactly like this. It's a common problem. This is a specific programming issue. Obviously it is open to discussion, but hey, what isn't in programming? :) If 10 different people would give me a 10 word answer, describing their idea to solve it, I would be happy enough and possibly would be able to come up with a solution of my own.

Once again, I do understand your point, but I believe this is exactly the kind of question that can make use of the brilliant programmers existing around here :)

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but this is not *my* opinion, I'm just helping to convey the community's stance. There are many articles written about this: [From the FAQ: "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](http://stackoverflow.com/faq); http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28559/subjective-question-on-stack-overflow. [Stack Overflow Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is a good place for extended discussion.

Comment: That's the project I'm currently working on.  The codebase is over 30k lines currently.  I'd suggest you go with a Mail Merge in Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to look at JasperReports. It can output templates to PDF. I believe it can also run as an applet.

For a more modern look, you could write an ajax client that talked to a java server to call Jasper there.

Comment: Thanks for your input Neil. I will look into it and produce some feedback soon

Comment: I've checked it and it doesn't seem to be exactly what I need. Although it is powerful, i am afraid it is too powerful. Maybe I didn't explain myself well. The need is not for an analytical too, but yes for a tool that can be used to design report templates and then fill them with data. But without any kind of analytical capabilities. They might range from simple labels (with a serial number, voltage, price, etc) to reports of trials but in which the data is just to be fetched and colated, no need for fancy analysis of relations or patterns. Hope I was not confusing. Thanks a lot anyways! :)

Comment: You don't need to use the fancy reporting stuff. You can make simple bar codes or labels or what have you. Does have good database connectivity. Might be overkill for your app though. Also consider pdftk

Comment: Thank you Neil. I looked further into JarperReports and it is true, I don't need to use the fancy stuff, and it seems powerful enough to fit almost any kind of needs. I will probably use it, I still have to talk to management.
Pdftk, although it is a powerful tool, doesnt' tackle our main problem: the template design. 
Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly a common requirement - customisable templates for reports/documents.  Web-editing facilities are one way of approaching the problem, but it seems very hard to get the web-ui to marry well to an output PDF (pagination alone is a significant roadblock).

[Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) (a commercial document generation engine) seems like a pretty good fit here for providing the customisable-template capability and output to PDF etc.  Because the "templates" are basic word or openoffice writer documents anyone can edit them (though some templates become complex enough you would avoid this for some customer/user groups).

A common implementation (which sounds like a solution to one of your key requirements) using Docmosis is to provide a set of templates in the application and allow the users to download, modify then upload back into the system.  The templates take immediate effect and Docmosis has some interesting features to assist users detect and find errors in their template (such as writing errors into the produced PDF/doc as footnotes to describe what is wrong).
Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

I hope that helps.